# How are unrelated modes enabled?

Tags: init-file, minor-mode, performance

I've been an emacs user for about a year now and I use it for Haskell programming. I chose to go the vanilla emacs route and customized a plain init file as I went along.

Over time, however, I realise that emacs started getting quite sluggish on my computer. The computer is not the bottleneck: its a powerful machine with 32GB of RAM.

My suspicion is that I have too many modes enabled, and hence my question: how do I debug where the modes are being enabled from?

For example; the current list of emacs modes I have enabled in a Haskell buffer are:

```
Enabled minor modes: Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition
Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption Autopair Autopair-Global Blink-Cursor
Cl-Old-Struct-Compat Company Desktop-Save Diff-Auto-Refine Dimmer
Display-Line-Numbers Eldoc Erc-Button Erc-Fill Erc-Irccontrols
Erc-List Erc-Match Erc-Menu Erc-Move-To-Prompt Erc-Netsplit
Erc-Networks Erc-Noncommands Erc-Pcomplete Erc-Readonly Erc-Ring
Erc-Sound Erc-Stamp Erc-Track Evil Evil-Commentary Evil-Local
Evil-Surround Evil-Visual-Mark File-Name-Shadow Flx-Ido Flycheck
Font-Lock Frames-Only Global-Display-Line-Numbers Global-Eldoc
Global-Evil-Surround Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit
Global-Magit-File Global-Undo-Tree Haskell-Indentation
Highlight-Indentation Hindent Ido-Everywhere Intero Intero-Global
Line-Number Magit-Auto-Revert Magit-File Mouse-Wheel Override-Global
Popwin Projectile Rainbow-Delimiters Recentf Shell-Dirtrack Subword
Tooltip Transient-Mark Undo-Tree Which-Key Winner Yas
```

I can spot multiple ERC related modes which seem to be enabled, and they make no sense since:

- ERC is not running at this time
- I'm in a Haskell buffer

Moreover, I'm not too keen on starting over with a vanilla emacs configuration for 2 reasons:

- If this has happened now, it will likely happen again in future
- I'd like to dig into what enables these ERC modes

My init file [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/asheshambasta/7344acf78aa225d120edb6869c4e1683)

Can anyone help?

EDIT 2: 
I experienced a crash recently. 
[The stacktrace doesn't really say much.](https://gist.github.com/asheshambasta/d2e38fa5518d26e689c3ba2152e38acd)

Comment: Let the [profiler](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html) run for some time (`profiler-start`, `profiler-report`, `profiler-stop`) and identify the largest culprits before optimizing.

Comment: The ERC modes are probably global modes, they seem to get enabled as soon as you do `M-x erc` (I just tried it in an `emacs -Q` session).

Comment: You need to compile with debug symbols to get useful stacktraces.

Comment: Turn off ~half of the modes, especially ones you suspect aren't currently relevant, and see how that affects performance. Then turn off 1/4, 1/8, 1/16,... to try to see which modes are costing you (and don't seem to be helping you). This is generally pretty quick. (Otherwise: yes, use profiler or other benchmarking code.)